how to write a condition is pine editor that detects the open/close of a candle through moving averages
I am trying to write a strategy in the pine editor on Tradingview so that if a candle crosses through both moving averages in a single candle, I will get a long or short condition. for example, the red candle in the attached image would signal a short condition. any help would be much appreciated
Candle example
Tried looking through functions referencing the open and close of candles to input into a function but could not find the correct language or formatting. All I have been able to find so far are conditions referencing the action of indicators and not the candle itself

I use a similiar strategy written in Python, so if I try to translate this to Pinescript the code should be like short_condition = open > ema1 > close and open > ema2 > close. Can you give it a try?

Thank you August, that helped a lot! here is what I got:
longCondition = ((open < ema21 and open < ema9) and (close > ema9 and close > ema21))
Perhaps it could be written in simpler terms but this is what I got. also worth noting,  I previously defined the ema9 and ema 21 as : ema9 = ta.ema(close, 9) and ema21 = ta.ema(close, 21)

Since you want to check if the cross happens on the current bar, you should check if the bar opened below/above those EMAs and closed above/below them.
Something like below will do:
short_condition = barstate.isconfirmed and (open > ema9) and (open > ema21) and (close < ema9) and (close < ema21)

barstate.isconfirmed is there to prevent repainting.
This is easy for two EMAs. If you have multiple, then you can use math.max() and math.min() to simplify.
Example for 10 EMAs:
ema_min = math.min(ema1, ema2, ema3, ema4, ema5, ema6, ema7, ema8, ema9, ema19)
ema_max = math.max(ema1, ema2, ema3, ema4, ema5, ema6, ema7, ema8, ema9, ema19)

short_condition = barstate.isconfirmed and (open > ema_max) and (close < ema_min)  // If the candle opened above the highest EMA and closed below the lowest EMA, it must have crossed all of them

